# How can I use VBA to automatically create hyperlinks between cells and sheets named after text in those cells?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to create a VBA code that can be run to hyperlink cells in a column with sheets named after those cells. We're building a maintenance log and on the master sheet all the machines are listed. We then have sheets created to capture service data and other information on each piece of equipment. The workbook is very large so we wanted to hyperlink the cells with their respective sheets. I have been going through 1 by 1 and linking them but if I ever need to update or redo the log as we're in trial stages, I don't want to spend the time again.

Is there a way this can be done in VBA? We've made modules to automatically create a sheet based on a template and the new machine names but it's a lot of meticulous work linking all the machines to their sheets.

Column data position

[image: Column data position]

Matching sheet

[image: Matching sheet]

One of my coworkers used this but it goes through and rewrites all the data in the tooling number column, throwing all the data in rows out of sync with their respective tooling numbers. We just want tooling numbers (column B) to hyperlink to sheets that are named exctly the same as what is in column B.

```
Sub CreateHyperLinks()
    Dim x As Worksheet
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 0
    For Each x In Worksheets
    Counter = Counter + 1
    If Counter = 1 Then GoTo Donothing
        With ActiveCell
            .Value = x.Name
            .Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, "", x.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=x.Name, ScreenTip:="Click here to go to the Worksheet"
            With Worksheets(Counter)
                .Range("A1").Value = "Back to " & ActiveSheet.Name
                .Hyperlinks.Add Sheets(x.Name).Range("A1"), "", _
                "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & ActiveCell.Address, _
                ScreenTip:="Return to " & ActiveSheet.Name
            End With
        End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Donothing:
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub CreateHyperLinks()
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, m, c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or active workbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("Master")
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        'exclude any sheets you want to skip
        If ws.Name <> wsMaster.Name And ws.Name <> "Template" Then
            'look for matching value in ColB on master sheet
            m = Application.Match(ws.Name, wsMaster.Columns("B"), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then  'got a match?
                Set c = wsMaster.Cells(m, "B")
                DoLink c, ws.Range("a1") 'link to sheet
                DoLink ws.Range("a1"), wsMaster.Range("A1"), _
                       "Back to " & wsMaster.Name 'link back to Master sheet
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
   
End Sub

'Hyperlink two ranges in the same workbook
Sub DoLink(FromCell As Range, ToCell As Range, Optional LinkText As String = "")
    FromCell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FromCell, Address:="", _
             SubAddress:="'" & ToCell.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & ToCell.Address(False, False), _
             TextToDisplay:=IIf(Len(LinkText) > 0, LinkText, FromCell.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.