Linking cells (In multiple columns) with a text string to a sheet within the same workbook, with the same name
I have cells in column B,D,F,H,J in a sheet called "Table of Contents" where I want to run through the cells in the entire column to look for a sheet in the workbook with the same name/text string and hyper link to A1.  Below is my current code, however it stops if there is a range of empty cells before another set of text. I want this to run through the entire column range I have listed.
Sub CreateHyperLinks()
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, m, c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("Table of Contents")
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsMaster.Name And ws.Name <> "Table of Contents" Then
            m = Application.Match(ws.Name, wsMaster.Range("B:J"), 0)
                Set c = wsMaster.Cells(m, "B:J")
                DoLink c, ws.Range("a1")
                DoLink ws.Range("a1"), wsMaster.Range("A1"), _
                       "Back to " & wsMaster.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
   
End Sub

Sub DoLink(FromCell As Range, ToCell As Range, Optional LinkText As String = "")
    FromCell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FromCell, Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="'" & ToCell.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & ToCell.Address(False, False), _
    TextToDisplay:=IIf(Len(LinkText) > 0, LinkText, FromCell.Text)
End Sub


You can't use MATCH over multiple columns - you'll need to use Find() instead.  wsMaster.Cells(m, "B:J") is not valid. Code looked familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191012/478884

You need to use Find() if you want to search over multiple columns:
Sub CreateHyperLinks()
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, f As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("Table of Contents")
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsMaster.Name And ws.Name <> "Table of Contents" Then
            Set f = wsMaster.Range("B:J").Find(ws.Name, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then        'got a match?
                DoLink f, ws.Range("a1")
                DoLink ws.Range("a1"), wsMaster.Range("A1"), _
                       "Back to " & wsMaster.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub DoLink(FromCell As Range, ToCell As Range, Optional LinkText As String = "")
    FromCell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FromCell, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'" & ToCell.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & ToCell.Address(False, False), _
        TextToDisplay:=IIf(Len(LinkText) > 0, LinkText, FromCell.text)
End Sub


Thanks for this solution, works flawlessly.  Didn't realize I was using your code, pretty cool if you ask me. If you don't mind me asking, f is a function that is identifying the range I want to look at in the worksheet I am adding hyperlinks to,  and then looking at every spreadsheet in the book?

f is just a variable of type Range, which is assigned to the result from Find() - if there's no match then Find() returns Nothing so that's what the If Not f Is Nothing  is testing for.

One last question, what do I need to change if I want to give this macro to someone else or use it on a different workbook?  It seems its not liking me adding it to my Personal Work to store macros, it just gives me a runtime error, with subscript not found.

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Thanks again, I was doing ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, but wasn't working.  Thank you for your time.  Learned a lot as I'm still relatively new to VBA.
